# ios not finding a txt file using stringWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a text file `thetext.txt`. Which is in my project and is copied on build, in build settings. In the same way that my GL shaders and textures are (which work fine.)

```
NSError *errorReading;
NSArray *linesOfText = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"thetext.txt"
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                          error:&errorReading]
             componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSLog(@"Reading error  %@",errorReading);
```

It prints the following to console.

```
Reading error  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x896fff0 {NSFilePath=thetext.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x896ff60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
```

Have I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This fails because you are passing the file name and not the path to the file. Try something like this

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thetext" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *errorReading;
NSArray *linesOfText = [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                      error:&errorReading]
                componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"Reading error  %@",errorReading);
```

Hopefully there will be no error!

Comment: Thank you :) thats working great now (will accept when SO lets me)